# Difference between string scanning and JSON parsing for a JSON string

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, string-search

Basically, I have a JSON string that could be found at the link [Six Critics](http://sixcritics.com/?json=1). When I use JSON parsing to separate fields in the string,  in the asynctask `onPostExecute`, the fragment is refreshed each time it is viewed. But when I use string scanning methods by getting the substring between the indices of two delimiters, the fragment content is not refreshed if the fragment was loaded before.

What would be the cause of this behaviour? Is JSON parsing too intensive as such? What would be the suggested walk around for this?

**EDIT:**

```
JSONObject jsonWholePage = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray posts = jsonWholePage.optJSONArray("posts");

for(int i=0; I<posts.length(); i++){
  JSONObject postObject = posts.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONArray cate = postObject.optArray("categories");
  int num_cate = cate.length();
  String category = cate.getJSONObject(0).optString("title");

  String title = postObject.optString("title");

  //do something with title and category
```

I'm am using the default Android JSON library `org.json.*`.

Comment: Can you provide some example code, please? If you have json, then you should parse with the provided tools, not substring

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to help you. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well then, let me add the actual code.

Comment: Instead of parsing the json string manually, try using google's gson java library that can be used to convert a json string to an equivalent Java object - https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: @Clive Seebregts I think you could phrase your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the `JSON` string manually, try using the Google's `GSON` library that can be used to convert a `JSON` string into an equivalent Java object.

Use jsonschema2pojo to auto-generate the POJO (Java) classes you need from your `JSON` string.

Steps:

1. Add `GSON` library by adding the following line to the `app/build.gradle` file: `dependencies { compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4' }`
2. Go to [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).
3. Copy and paste the `JSON` string into the output box.
4. Select `JSON` for Source type.
5. Select None for Annotation style.
6. Click the Preview button.
7. Copy and paste the generated classes into your project.
8. To automatically parse the `JSON` string use the following code: `Example example = new Gson().fromJson(json, Example.class);`

Comment: I'm stuck at step 3. Should I paste any `JSON` string there?

Comment: Yes, paste your `JSON` string into there. You may need to reduce the size of your `JSON`...

Comment: But there is a default string that is already in that box. Can I use it instead? I'm a little bit confused why I need to paste my JSON string there. Why can't I just use any other JSON string since this is a tool that should help me generate Java objects from JSON strings?

Comment: The tool needs your specific `JSON` string to generate the appropriate classes the GSON library needs to convert  your `JSON` string in too

Comment: But I will be using several different JSON strings. If I need to give it my specific string, does it mean that I will have to generate different classes for each one of them? I need to do everything programmatically.

Comment: And also, I wouldn't know the actual string until at runtime.

Comment: If the `JSON` schema is different then yes you will have to

Comment: If that's the case, then maybe this doesn't really solve my problem, thanks for the help.